# Is it possible with TypeScript to get al list of keys from an object, which is typed also?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function getFeature(key: string) { ... }
```

In my code I want to declare all possible features with a fallback like:

```
const FEATURES = {
  'my-feature': {
    fallback: true
  },
  'another-feature': {
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

I want to use a type for this object, so the `fallback` property must be a boolean. So I created:

```
type FeatureMap = Record<string, { fallback: boolean}>

const FEATURES: FeatureMap = {
  'my-feature': {
    fallback: true
  },
  'another-feature': {
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

Now I want the list of Feature keys, so I have to parse the correct feature key into the function `getFeature`.

```
type FeatureMap = Record<string, { fallback: boolean}>

const FEATURES: FeatureMap = {
  'my-feature': {
    fallback: true
  },
  'another-feature': {
    fallback: false
  }
}

type FeatureKey = keyof typeof FEATURES;

function getFeature(key: FeatureKey) { ... }
```

But now I get that the `key` argument in the `getFeature` function should be a `string` and not one of the keys of FEATURES.
When I remove the `FeatureMap` type from the `const Features`, I get all the names, but then `fallback` isn't typed.

Is there a way to get it both work at once?

Comment: [`satisifies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)

Comment: Yeah, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE7rbm) shows how you'd use it here; see the answers to the other questions for more info

Comment: Wow, I know why its called that. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.